# Spring cannot find bean xml configuration file: "Failed to import bean definitions from relative location"

Tags: java, xml, spring, applicationcontext

My resources folder in Eclipse (src/main/resources) contains 
- beans.xml and
- persons.xml

[image]

In beans.xml I use `<import resource="person.xml"/>`

If I load the context via

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
        "beans.xml");
```

the error "Failed to import bean definitions from relative location" [person.xml] appears.

If I replace the import with the content of person.xml it works. Why I cant use the import resource?

Content of beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Works if used    
    <bean id="person" class="com.example.demo.domain.Person"></bean> 
     -->
    <!--  Does not work if used 
    <import resource="classpath:person.xml"/>
    -->

</beans>
```

Content of person.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>

    <bean id="person" class="com.example.demo.domain.Person"></bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please try with `<import resource="classpath:person.xml"/>`

instead of `<import resource="person.xml"/>`

Comment: Then I get "Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:person.xml]"

Comment: can you share the content of beans.xml and person.xml

Comment: I add the content in the question above

Comment: use the following person.xml    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="person" class="com.example.demo.domain.Person"></bean>
</beans>`